# Why PopupWindow still show?

Tags: java, android, view, popupwindow

I created a `PopupWindow` on a View, and my device screen is 2560 x 1600. I used this code to show `PopupWindow`

```
showAtLocation(view, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, 2700, 1700);
```

I think `PopupWindow` will not show because the `position(2700, 1700)` is Invisible.
But you know, I still see the `PopupWindow` showing on screen.

what is this problem and how to solve it?

Thanks

Comment: details are not enough to give you an answer whats the view you pass there ?

Comment: @Charuක the View is SurfaceView

Comment: Is that the same one you use with the setContentView  ?

Comment: it is a drawablw